# Regular Expression to accept all the decimals from 0 to 100

Tags: regex

I want to modify my existing Regular Expression which accepts decimals from 0 to 99.99

```
\d{0,2}(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

i want this to be **accept**

```
100
100.0
100.00
```

and should **not accept**

```
100.1
100.02
101
```

Can anyone help me modify the above RE

Comment: Why are you using a regular expression for this? Can't you just use a numeric comparison?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, that would allow 999.99

Comment: @Ben that comment was before the edit :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess it's best to add the test for 100 as a special case using `|`:

```
^(\d{0,2}(\.\d{1,2})?|100(\.00?)?)$
```

Comment: That won't match 100.000 though. Not sure if he wants to match more than 2 decimal places, but if so: `^(\d{0,2}(\.\d+)?|100(\.0+)?)$`

Comment: This accepts two-digit numbers with leading zeros (e.g. `02`, `05.32`). To exclude leading zeros, use: `^([1-9]?\d)(\.\d{1,2})?|100(\.00?)?)$`.

Comment: all these variants are giving me eslint `Unsafe Regular Expressioneslint(security/detect-unsafe-regex)` warning.

Answer (score 6):

#### Use Floating-Point Comparisons Instead

You already have answers for doing this with a regular expression, but it's usually more efficient to handle this as a floating-point comparison with boundary conditions. For example, using Ruby:

```rb
number = 99
number.to_f >= 0 and number.to_f <= 100
=> true

number = 100.01
number.to_f >= 0 and number.to_f <= 100
=> false
```

In these examples, the variable is cast as a float so that strings and integers are compared properly, and then the float is compared to the boundary conditions of zero and 100. It's quick, easy to write, and (most importantly) *easy to read*.

Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me from 00.00 to 99.99

```
/^(?=.*\d)\d{0,2}(?:\.\d{0,2})?$/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
100(\.0{1,2})?$|\d{0,2}(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

Comment: Forgot the trailing $; fixed now. Why don't you use a starting anchor as well, though?

Answer (score 0):

```
(100(\.[0]{1,2})?|[0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, this will help you "^(100(.0{0,2}?)?$|([1-9]{0,1})([0-9]{1})((.[0-9]{0,2})|(\,[0-9]{0,2}))?)$"

It will match everything between this:
0-100,
0.0 - 100.0,
0.00 - 100.00
and all this with comma.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(0*(\d{1,2}(\.\d+)?)|\.\d+|100(\.0+$)?)$
```

This will apply to any values between 0-100 with decimals that are valid for most programming languages

```
valid: 0, 0.2, .1, 0001.020, 9, 010, 100.0000
invalid: -1, 100.010, 1., ., empty
```